# How to conditionally remove form field=required

Tags: django

It's simple to require a field based on the state of another:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form)
    foo = forms.BooleanField()
    bar = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('foo') and not self.cleaned_data.get('bar'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('With foo you must have bar')
```

How can I do the reverse and **remove** a field requirement instead (**without changing it in the model**)?

E.g.

```
class FooForm(forms.Form)
    foo = forms.BooleanField()
    bar = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('foo'):
            # No foo, no bar required
            del bar.required??
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `bar` to be not required, and in `clean` check if `foo` is False and `bar` doesn't exist:

```py
class FooForm(forms.Form)
    foo = forms.BooleanField()
    bar = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        # No foo and no bar, bad
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('foo') and not self.cleaned_data.get('bar'):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Bar is required without Foo")
```

Comment: Thanks, but not the question - I already provided that as my counter example. What I need is how to handle `required=True`

Comment: @alias51 - this is what you asked for. When `foo` is False, `bar` is required; when `foo` is True, `bar` is not required.